# Improve JPA performance Bidirectional mapping " n+1 select "

Tags: hibernate, jpa, eclipselink, spring-data-jpa

I have two entity Group and Person , i use bidirectional mapping and in this case i have n+1 queries instead of one.

```
public class Person extends BaseBean {
Group group ;
//getter and setter
}
public class Groupextends BaseBean {
List<Person>  childPersons;
//getter and setter
}
```

I use eclipselink for the mapping .

```
<entity name="person" class="tn.waycon.alquasar2.gp.model.Person">
        <attributes>
            <many-to-one name="group" fetch="EAGER">
                <join-column name="group_id" />
            </many-to-one>
        </attributes>
    </entity>

<entity name="group_of_persons" class="tn.waycon.alquasar2.gp.model.Group">
        <attributes>    
            <one-to-many name="childPersons" mapped-by="group" fetch="EAGER">
                <join-fetch>OUTER</join-fetch> 
                <cascade>
                    <cascade-all />
                </cascade>
            </one-to-many>  
        </attributes>

    </entity>
```

And i use spring data jpa to fetch the data.

```
@Query("select p from person p left join fetch p.group")
 List<Person> getAll();
```

the problem is , when i select the list of person the getAll function generate 1 query to select all person and n query to get all the Person By the group_id .
This is the log generated by getAll() function:

SELECT t1.ID, t1.activity, t1.last_name, t1.matricule, t0.NAME, t0.parent_id FROM PERSON t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN GROUP_OF_PERSONS t0 ON (t0.ID = t1.group_id)

Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--SELECT ID,  employ_date, first_name, gender, last_name, matricule, phone_number, title, group_id FROM PERSON WHERE (group_id = ?)
bind => [5302]

Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--SELECT ID,  employ_date, first_name, gender, last_name, matricule, phone_number, title, group_id FROM PERSON WHERE (group_id = ?)
    bind => [6965]

Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--SELECT ID, employ_date, first_name, gender, last_name, matricule, phone_number, title, group_id FROM PERSON WHERE (group_id = ?)
    bind => [6980]

Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--SELECT ID,  employ_date, first_name, gender, last_name, matricule, phone_number, title, group_id FROM PERSON WHERE (group_id = ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your Person->Group relationship.  It is marked as eager and without any fetching options, forces a separate query for each Person that is read in from the initial query.  Mark the query to use joining or batch fetching as discussed above, or use the same or similar OUTER option that you have on the Group->Person relationship to have it all fetched in a single query.

Better yet, leave it as lazy unless you really need the relationship fetched in every single part of your application.

Answer (score 0):

You're using fetch in your query (to include 'group' child elements of parent Person entity). This is the expected behavior and you'll have the usual N+1 SQL SELECT problem as a result. However, since you are using EclipseLink as your JPA provider, you can do optimizations such as using `@JoinFetch`, `@BatchFetch` annotations (which are only specific to EclipseLink).

Check out this [link](http://vard-lokkur.blogspot.com/2011/05/eclipselink-jpa-queries-optimization.html) or see EclipseLink documentation for more info.